# Why embedding functions inside of strings is different than variables

Tags: php, php-parser

I've asked a question like this before but this one is different, this is more about parsing logic.

My previous questions was about how to embed a function inside of a string (double-quoted) and I received this answer:

```
$date = "date";
echo "This page is under construction<br/><br/>Current Date: {$date('l jS \of F Y')}";
```

And after that I started to wonder why this one below is not working while the the one above is working fine:

```
echo "This page is under construction<br/><br/>Current Date: {date('l jS \of F Y')}";
```

How is the logic behind the parsing process even though variables are working pretty fine inside of the strings.

I read that after PHP parser `$` sign, it tries to find appropriate variable to parse and run and also to delimit the variable name we also use curly braces `{}` and that is also something I understand fairly.

But why this kind of syntax is seemed required while developing the parser engine for functions because at first it didn't make any sense to me.

**Basically, why do I need to define a variable which hold string representaion of the function name such as below:**

`$date = "date";`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex):

> Note:
>
> Functions, method calls, static class
>   variables, and class constants inside
>   {$} work since PHP 5. However, the
>   value accessed will be interpreted as
>   the name of a variable in the scope in
>   which the string is defined. Using
>   single curly braces ({}) will not work
>   for accessing the return values of
>   functions or methods or the values of
>   class constants or static class
>   variables.

Here is a hack around this though:

```
function _expression($x) { return $x; }
$e = '_expression';

echo "This page is under construction<br/><br/>Current Date: {$e(date('l jS \of F Y'))}";
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple. The syntax for any complex parsing in double quotes to occur is **`{$`**. No other byte sequence will trigger this behaviour in PHP. That syntax token is know as [`T_CURLY_OPEN`](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php).

And that you can use functions with that is only a *by-product* of PHP supporting object and array expressions with it.